# Spatie Permission Role

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I currently have a spatie package installed on my CRM and really don't know how it works.
I have Superadmin level/ Company level / Employee Level / Client Level

I would need to create a section on the sidebar of superadmin where I could asign different permisions such as create projects and leads and having the option on employees to create projects and leads.

Basically, Company already has permission for that, but employees don't.
My issue is I need employees to access the create button of both projects and leads.

And if anyone could help me in adding a section to superadmin for a section on the sidebar menu to be able to assign different role types and specified permissions it would be very helpful.

Thank you!!

Comment: And what have you tried ? can you show us a bit of code ? you need a controller that will update roles like so : `$role->permissions()->sync($requestData['permissions']);` it will allow admins to change role permissions. You will also need a controller for adding permissions like so : `Permission::create(['name' => $requestData['name']]);` and update them with `$permission->update(['name' => $requestData['name']]))`

Comment: Yes basically I have all the controllers done, but Ineed to give access and permission to employees to creade, edit and delete leads.

Comment: Source code is to long stack won't let me upload it

Comment: I have assigned permissions trough the controller but everytime I access the view of leads (the sales) as a employee or company, I get a 500 error wich is a permission. I can't tell were to find the solution to this.

Comment: When you create a permission, you need to use it in your code, for example `$user->can('my.permission);` if you have an error 500 it's something else, you have an error in  your code. You will also need a controller to change user role

Answer (score 0):

These videos will help you understand how spatie works. When I have worked with Spatie Permissions I would create all the permissions you need e.g "create_project" and "create_lead" and then give those permissions to the relevant roles rather than to a user. $role->givePermissionTo('create_lead');
You can then check if the user has permission to do the action in the route middleware and also in the request (if it has one).

Spatie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgToi0uiMNQ&ab_channel=LaravelDaily

Middleware: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sukS7QOBpK0&t=9s&ab_channel=LaravelDaily

Second Part:
Ok so in your blade files you can use `@can('permission:create_project")` to render the create project button and sidebar links, if a role has that permission it will render. So assign this to the employee role aswell.

To create your role and permission assigning section.
In the route to the "create_project" page and controller methods you need to use "Route::middleware('permission:create_project')->get('your route here')" to use the spatie permissions middleware, assuming you have registered it like in the video.

Then use that to create CRUD methods in your controller for updating permissions from the methods you can find here. https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/basic-usage

Then assign the relevant permissions to each role.

Comment: Thank you the videos were very helpful. Still haven'tsolved the issue tho.